# How to translate this "合計約150件のブログの中から何点かを紹介します"

Tags: meaning, translation, words

"過去3年間、合計約150件のブログの中から何点かを紹介します。"
the translation in the blog i encounter it was: "I will share some of the blogs from the past three years, which in total amount to about 150 blogs".

**Wouldn't it be:** "I will share some points (spots) in the blogs from the past three years, which in total amount to about 150 blogs"**?**

https://www.japonin.com/free-learning-tools/teachers-blog/blogger/listings/293-kamioka.html?start=0
Posted by JOI teachers on Saturday, 05 November 2022 in Teachers' stories

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In short, no. This 何点か is a reference to (part of) something already introduced. Since the only plausible thing to refer to in the immediate context (at least in the quoted sentence) is "blogs", that would be picked up. If you want it to refer to locations, you need to explicitly introduce them first, like:

> 過去のブログで紹介した場所の中から何点かを紹介します

or maybe

> 私はこれまで色々な場所について書きました。今日は、過去のブログの中から何点かを紹介します。